# Regarding kalman filter implementation

Tags: kalman-filter, matlab

I think I might have originally posted this in the wrong stack exchange forum, [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3367799/regarding-implementation-of-kalman-filter). I think this might be the right place, I am not sure if posting again is considered "bad style", I apologize if this is the case.

My questions is regarding the implementation of a discrete time Kalman filter assuming the time update occurs much more often than measurement update. I'll be specifically looking at the covariance propagation and Kalman gain equations.

Given a D.T. KF with the following state space model:
$$
\hat{x}_{k+1} = F \hat{x}_k + G \omega_k
$$
$$
\hat{y}_k = C \hat{x}_k + \upsilon_k
$$
and assuming $\hat{x}^-(0)$ and $P^-(0)$ are known as well as the process and measurement noise intensities (Q and R respectively) the relevant equations are:

Gain update:
$$
K = P^-C^T (CP^- C^T + R)^{-1}
$$
Measurement update
$$
P^- = F P^+ F^T + Q
$$
Time Update:
$$
P^+ = (I-KC)P^-
$$

The difficulty I am having is with respect to implementation and how to properly initialize. A pseudo code example of what I think should be done is the following:

```
% Assume P0 is given
Pp = P0;                                       % Initializing P-
for i=1:N                                      % N = number of measurement updates
    for j=1:m                                  % m = number of time updates in one measurement update
        Pp = F*Pu*F' + Qd;                     % covariance prop
    end
    K = Pp*C'*(R + C*Pp*C')^(-1)        % update gain
    Pu = (eye(nx) - K*C)*Pp;            % measurement update
end
```

But this has the problem that the first iteration `Pp` cannot compute because there has yet to be a measurement update. This is easily solved by forcing a measurement update before any time updates. Maybe it's just me but it seems kind of incorrect to NEED a measurement update before any time updates.

Answer (score 2):

D.T Kalman filter time update equations (predict) with initial estimates for $\hat{x}_k$ and $P_{k}$

1. Project the state ahead: $\hat{x}^-_{k+1} = F\hat{x}_{k}+Bu_{k}$
2. Project the error covariance ahead: $P^-_{k+1} = FP_{k}F^T+Q$

Measurement equations (correct)

1. Compute the Kalman gain: $K_{k+1} = P^-_{k+1}C^T(CP^-_{k+1}C^T+R)^{-1}$
2. Update estimate with measurement: $\hat{x}_{k+1} = \hat{x}^-_{k+1}+K_{k+1}(y_{k+1}-C\hat{x}^-_{k+1})$
3. Update the error covariance: $P_{k+1}= (I-K_{k+1}C)P^-_{k+1}$

Note the super minus sign is for a priori estimate.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are misunderstanding some of the Kalman filter equations. There is no such thing as a time update.

What you have shown here

> Time Update:
>
> $$P^+ = (I-KC)P^-$$

is the updating of the uncertainty/covariance from the measurement update. You can see this labeled properly on the [wikipedia article on the kalman filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kalman_filter).

In your code your initial value of Pu should be set to the uncertainty of your initial value. If you don't know this then usually *Identity* will work and it will update itself accordingly.

Also in general I don't really see how your code is going to work. You shouldn't really have two for loops. You should have 1 for loop and and an if state for the measurement update. Generally I would also separate the update and prediction into two functions.

I don't know your application and this is an EKF but try to structure your code similarly to this [example](https://github.com/AtsushiSakai/PythonRobotics/blob/master/Localization/extended_kalman_filter/extended_kalman_filter.py).

Comment: I think we have a misunderstanding in terminology, time update is used in many textbooks as a colloquialism for the prediction step when one is working with an open form Kalman filter, i.e. separate prediction and estimation.

Comment: The Pu is a typo that I had not noticed, I will fix this.

Comment: The dual for loops is to account for speed differences when information is available for prediction vs estimation steps. For example a gnss unit at 1 Hz + IMU at 100Hz in an INS context.

Comment: Ok. Your post also has the measurement update and time update wrong. They need to be switched. Your code still seems to have problems. The Kalman gain ***K*** should not be in the prediction step(but instead in the measurement step). Also it only makes sense right now if ***m*** the number of prediction steps is constant between the measurement updates.

Comment: I'm not sure where it is written that measurement necessarily must happen before time or vice verse.

Comment: In addition m shouldn't need to be constant, AFAIK a benefit of Kalman filtering is ability to take measurements as they come so to speak. So a measurement update can be delayed or ignored if necessary.

Comment: That being said I acknowledge that the prediction step should happen at regular intervals, given that the matrices are discretized wrt. a certain sampling frequency.

Comment: Not in the code but your equations. You have measurement update as $P^- = F P^+ F^T + Q$ and Time/Prediction Update as $P^+ = (I-KC)P^-$. These should be reversed.

Agreed just saying how the pseudo code is written right now then it needs to be constant.